# How to check if Accelerometer is supported in react native?

Tags: react-native, expo

How can I check if Accelerometer is support with react native and expo?

I have tried the following

```
const accel = Accelerometer.addListener(this.determineShake);

if (!accel) //not supported, do something else
```

this didn't work.

Comment: maybe try this library: https://github.com/react-native-sensors/react-native-sensors
It seems to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

From their implementation, it seems they locally check whether or not it's active, and then decide to call a callback:

```
if ([[self manager] isAccelerometerAvailable]) {
  _accelerometerHandlers[scopedSensorModule] = handlerBlock;
}
```

[From Github](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/eafa96e0d6fdab6bf8efdd819598e8a558154838/packages/expo-sensors/ios/EXSensors/EXSensorsManager.m#L57:L59)

So you'll may want to detach from Expo and use [the suggested solution from @Nino9612](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53443968/how-to-check-if-accelerometer-is-supported-in-react-native#comment93761361_53443968), using the `catch` clause of a `Accelerometer` instance:

```
new Accelerometer()
  .then(observable => ...)
  .catch(error => console.warn('The sensor is not available'));
```

https://github.com/react-native-sensors/react-native-sensors#sensor-api

Answer (score 0):

```
Accelerometer.isAvailableAsync()
```

This API returns a Promise that resolves to a boolean denoting the availability of the sensor. See details at [doc.expo.ios/accelerometer](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/sdk/accelerometer/#api)